# Display IR image from XBOX 360 using Open Kinect via Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, linux, opencv, xbox360, libfreenect2

I would like to display on the computer screen the infra-red camera using an XBox Kinect 360.  This code below will open a new frame but the display is just a back frame and not the IR video feed. How can I get the frame to display the IR image?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import freenect
import cv2
def get_video():
    array,_ = freenect.sync_get_video(0,freenect.VIDEO_IR_10BIT)
    return array
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while 1:
        #get a frame from RGB camera
        frame = get_video()
        #display IR image
        cv2.imshow('IR image',frame)
        # quit program when 'esc' key is pressed
        k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I'm no expert on the subject, but I think I've found an answer by looking around on SO and github.  It seems that [`freenect.sync_get_depth`](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/wrappers/python/freenect.pyx) will get the depth image, and [`frame_convert.pretty_depth_cv`](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/wrappers/python/frame_convert.py) will make the output into an array for OpenCV.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: Robert, yes, thanks!  See the correct code below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clues Robert Prevost!  This code returns a frame showing the IR image.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import freenect
import numpy as np
import cv2

def get_video():
    array,_ = freenect.sync_get_video(0,freenect.VIDEO_IR_10BIT)
    return array
def pretty_depth(depth):
    np.clip(depth, 0, 2**10-1, depth)
    depth >>=2
    depth=depth.astype(np.uint8)
    return depth
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while 1:
        #get a frame from RGB camera
        frame = get_video()
        #display IR image
        frame = pretty_depth(frame)
        cv2.imshow('IR image',frame)

        # quit program when 'esc' key is pressed
        k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```